# Form element goes blank when I dispatchEvent()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, phantomjs

I am trying to write a PhantomJS script to automate submitting apps to the Amazon App Store. But I am having trouble submitting the form.  Here is the URL I use to submit apps: https://developer.amazon.com/application/new.html

Then on console I enter this code to test things out:
First command I issue is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('inputBlockTitle')[0].nextElementSibling.value='zzzzzz zzzzzz';
```

And all's good.

[image]

The next commands are ...

```
document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex = 16;
var evnt2 = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evnt2.initEvent("change",true,true);
```

... and again all is good ....

[image]

... but when I actually dispatch that event by executing ...

```
document.querySelector('select').dispatchEvent(evnt2);
```

... the application title goes blank!

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after days of trail and error I got something that works.  Not sure why this works but it does. Here are the series of commands I must issue:

```
var app_title_el = $(document.body).find('input')[0];
app_title_el.value='the title of the app';
var ap_ti_evnt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
ap_ti_evnt.initEvent("change", true, true);
app_title_el.dispatchEvent(ap_ti_evnt);
$(document.body).find('select')[0].selectedIndex = 16;
var evnt2 = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evnt2.initEvent("change",true,true);
$(document.body).find('select')[0].dispatchEvent(evnt2);
```